# Clicking text (list item) with Selenium and Powershell

Tags: powershell, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following HTML and I am trying to find a way (in Powershell) to click the "folder" list item, which appears when the "new" button is clicked.

```
<div>
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i>
    <span>new</span>
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down margin-none margin-left-xsmall"></i>
</div>
<div class="itg-popover qa-itg-popover borderless point-to-right arrow-direction-up arrow-position-right open" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">
    <span class="arrow-container" style="height: 0px; width: 10px; left: calc(100% - 0px); top: 100%;">
        <span class="arrow" style="border-width: 0px;">
        </span>
    </span>
    <div class="itg-popover-content qa-itg-popover-content" style="left: calc(100% + 0px); transform: translateX(-100%); top: calc(-1px + 100%);">
        <ul class="react-selectable-list qa-react-selectable-list">
            <li data-id="assset" class="selectable-list-item qa-selectable-list-item">
                <span class="sentence-case">
                    <a>document</a>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li data-id="folder" class="selectable-list-item qa-selectable-list-item">
                <span class="sentence-case">
                    <a>folder</a>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li data-id="file-upload" class="selectable-list-item qa-selectable-list-item">
                <span class="sentence-case">
                    <a>File Upload</a>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using the following code, I have clicked the "new" button:

```
$seleniumPath = 'C:\it\selenium'
Add-Type -Path "$seleniumPath\WebDriver.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$seleniumPath\WebDriver.Support.dll"
$chromedriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver
$chromedriver.Navigate().GoToUrl('https://<url>')
$chromedriver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@id='react-main']/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/i[2]").Click()
```

I thought I could create a SelectElement (so I could search by text) with this:

```
$SelectElement = [OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement]::new($chromedriver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@id='react-main']/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/i[2]"))
```

But I get this error:

> Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Element should have
> been select but was i"

Sure enough, if I look at the object, there's, "i":

```
WrappedDriver : OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver
TagName : i
Text : New
document
folder
File Upload
Enabled : True
Selected : False
Location : {X=1025,Y=102}
Size : {Width=95, Height=35}
Displayed : True
LocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView : {X=1025,Y=102}
Coordinates : OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteCoordinates
```

So the question in, how in the world do I click "folder"?

Comment: Looks like your XPath has `/i[2]` at the end of it. That would explain why you're getting the  `<i>` tag instead of the `<select>`. The error indicates you can't instantiate a `[OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement]` object by passing an `<i>` element to the `new()` method.
I can't give you the exact XPath becuase you haven't provided the entire HTML document. But you should be able to experiment with another XPath that ends in `/select`.

Comment: I will work on cleaning up the HTML. I could paste a link to all of it, but ctrl+f shows only one instance of /select, and it is not in an apparently useful spot. Is there any other way to create the object so I can select by visible text? When I click with Katalon running, it shows the target as, "link=folder".

Comment: You might try looking at some [examples of findby](https://www.ontestautomation.com/findby-strategies-for-selenium-explained/). There are other ways to find an element that are more robust and less dependent on the HTML structure than XPath... like finding by class or ID.

Comment: Yeah, but these elements don't have any useful identifiers (as far as I can see). This findby looks like I'll have the same issue instantiating an object as i do trying to create the SelectElement object.